# What does this code mean ? did this transfer a vector to an array?

Tags: c++

I have the code of a function below, that takes as parameter a pivot integer and a vector A. I would like to know what this `auto& A_ref = *A;` means. I am not familiar with &auto. Did this make the vector pointer an array ? and what is the value of doing such a thing

```
void function1(vector<int>* A, int pivot_index)
{
    auto& A_ref = *A;
    int pivot = A_ref[pivot_index];
}
```

Comment: `auto` is part of C++11 and causes the compiler to figure out the type itself. The compiler will use `*A` to figure out the type, and since `*A` is of type `std::vector<int>` then the type of `A_ref` will be a reference (because of the `&`) to that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the author of the code does not know how to use `operator []` with pointers:) or he wanted to simplify the access to the operator. So instead of

```
int pivot = ( *A )[pivot_index];
```

or

```
int pivot = A->operator[]( pivot_index );
```

he wrote

```
auto& A_ref = *A;
int pivot = A_ref[pivot_index];
```

*A has type `std::vector<int>`. So statement

```
auto& A_ref = *A;
```

can be written like

```
std::vector<int> & A_ref = *A;
```

`auto` allows the compiler to deduce the type of the object from the initializer expression.
For example

```
int x = 10;
auto y = x;
```

Here `y` has the same type as its initializer expression `x`. If you do not want to define a new object but want to define a reference to already existent object you can write for example

```
int x = 10;
auto &rx = x;
```

Take into account that class `std::vector` has overloaded subscript `operator []`. So you can access elements of a vector the same way as elements of an array.

Comment: My apologies, missed this somehow.

Answer (score 2):

auto is expanded by the compiler to match the rvalue that is assigned .
it will be expand to `vector<int>`

so the first line is equal to 
`vector<int>& A_ref = *A`

anyway , this code is not the safest or intuitive. you could simply write :

```
void function1(vector<int>& A, int pivot_index)
{
    int pivot = A[pivot_index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto this `auto` "Specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer."  So basically I think this "auto" is a matter of comfort in this case.

`*A` is returning the content of the pointer, i.e., the vector, and it is being hold by `A_ref`.

`A_ref[pivot_index]` is simply accessing to the vector.

If you wished to access the vector without `A_ref`, you should to something like

```
(*A)[pivot_index]
```